# How to Pass the asp:Label ID from an asp:CheckBox

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I've looked around different forums, but I couldn't find a method that allows me to call an asp:Label's id and pass it to a javascript function using an "onclick" from a nested asp:CheckBox within.

I want to pass both the checkbox ID and the label ID in the onclick="selectThisDemo2" call. Here's the code:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblRace1" runat="server" CssClass="lblDemo2 btn btn-primary">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRace1" CssClass="cbButtons" runat="server" onClick="selectThisDemo2(this.id, this.label.id)" Style="font-weight: normal" />
</asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered resolving your ID attributes within your `selectThisDemo2()` function?

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbRace1" CssClass="cbButtons" runat="server" onClick='selectThisDemo2()' Style="font-weight: normal" />
```

And adjusting your function to resolve them based on the element that triggered the event "`event.srcElement`" (and it's relatively positioned label) as seen below :

```
function selectThisDemo2(){
     // Get your current element
     var element = event.srcElement;
     // Get it's ID attribute
     var elementId = element.id;
     // Traverse up the generated markup and access your label (and it's ID)
     var labelId = element.parentElement.parentElement.id;
     // Do something here
}
```

**Example**

```js
function selectThisDemo2() {
  var element = event.srcElement;
  var elementId = element.id;
  var labelId = element.parentElement.parentElement.id;
  // Do something here
  alert(elementId + ',' + labelId);
}
```

```html
<span id="lblRace1" class="lblDemo2 btn btn-primary">
    <span class="cbButtons" style="font-weight: normal">
        <input id="cbRace1" type="checkbox" name="cbRace1" onclick="selectThisDemo2();">
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Woahhh, I didn't know you could do this! Thanks for opening my mind!!! :D